# PWM - signal modulation (sawtooth vs triangle signal)

Tags: pwm

In order to get the PWM signal out of a **sawtooth (ramp up/down)** I usualy use an operational amplifier and set the reference value with a potentiometer. This is how I can then modify the PWM by turning the potentiometer.

Is it possible to get a PWM signal out of a **triangle** signal using operational amplifier in a similar way?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Why would it be any different with a triangle than with a sawtooth?.

Comment: Yes.  A triangle wave will also work.  Heck, even a sine wave will work but the control signal from the pot will have a non-linear relationship with the PWM duty cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The difference is that the PWM pulse will be centered within the train rather than against either edge ([type 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation#Types)).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Are there any schematics for how to achieve this?

Comment: On what? How to generate a triangle wave, or on how to use it for PWM?

Comment: How to use it for PWM.

Comment: Given your initial question, I'm not really sure how you want me to answer that...

Comment: I have a triangle signal on input of a blackbox which outputs a PWM signal. What kind of a circuit must this blackbox be?

Comment: Uh... a comparator. Like you mention in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same thing.  Whether the leading edge is nearly vertical (sawtooth) or about the same slope as the other edge (triangle), makes no difference in a comparator producing a linearly varying duty cycle as a function of the reference voltage.

Draw it out and think about it.